# In inline equations, should I use parentheses to represent the sum of two or more variables?

Tags: formal-grammar

In inline equations, should I use parentheses to represent the sum of two or more variables?

Let me give an example.

Suppose that there are $5$ nodes, denoted by $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_5$, and each node has its own reward value according to its given weight.
We denote the reward value of node $i$ when its weight is $x_i$ by $f_i(x_i)$.

In this case, which of the following two sentences is better?

> The problem considered in this paper is the optimization problem with the goal of maximizing the sum reward with weight $x_i + y_i$ for node $i$.

> The problem considered in this paper is the optimization problem with the goal of maximizing the sum reward with weight $(x_i + y_i)$ for node $i$.

Comment: I would not use parantheses here since they are not necessary. I also think that the layout is more readerfriendly without parantheses, in particular if many lines or even several expressions in one line are written down. In the latter case, you can seperate the expressions by commas.

Comment: Both are good, none is better.